# Pyspark in google colab

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use pyspark on google colab. Every tutorial follows a similar method

```
!pip install pyspark # Import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession # Create a Spark Session
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate() # Check Spark Session Information
spark # Import a Spark function from library
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
```

But I get an error in

```
----> 4 spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate() # Check Spark Session Information
```

```
RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

I tried installing java using something like this

```
# Download Java Virtual Machine (JVM)
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
```

as suggested by the tutorials, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: what happen when you delete `.master("local[*]")`?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me so i post in case someone needs it.

```
!pip install pyspark
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
!apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
```

```
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql  as pyspark_sql
import pyspark.sql.types as pyspark_types
import pyspark.sql.functions  as pyspark_functions
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
```

```
# create the session
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.ui.port", "4050")

# create the context
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = pyspark_sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```